# How to track application launch

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How to track the application’s launch by the user, I found out that this is possible using accessibilityService, but I do not like this approach. I see in the play market applications that block other applications with a pin code, and they somehow track the launch of the application, and I give them only permission to view application statistics

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

The second option is to create a class that extends Application with a flag, for example isAppRunning, which will be true or false according if your application is on the foreground or not:

```
   public class MyAppContext extends Application {

   public boolean isAppRunning = true;

   public void setIsAppRunning(boolean v){
      isAppRunning = v;
   }

   public boolean isAppRunning(){
      return isAppRunning;
   }

}
```

Then on your AndroidManifest.xml you have to add this class so it will be used when your application starts. Just add android:name=".MyAppContext" under the application tag:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyAppContext"
```

Now in every activity that you have you should override onResume() and onPause() and set the flag to the corresponding value:

```
class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ((MyAppContext)getApplication()).setIsAppRunning(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        ((MyAppContext)getApplication()).setIsAppRunning(false);
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

On this way every time you start an Activity the value of isAppRunning in MyAppContext will be true, when you exit the Activity it will be false but if another Activity opens (for example if you pressed the back button so you are returning to the previous activity) the value will be immediately true again.

When you finally finish all your Activities none of the onResume() methods will be called and all the onPause() methods will be called so isAppRunning will be false and you know your Activity is no longer on the foreground.

So resuming, if isAppRunning is true your application is on the foreground (start the session tracking) otherwise it's gone (stop the session tracking). You can create a Timer in MyAppContext class to check the value of isAppRunning periodically, so it would be:

```
public class MyAppContext extends Application {

   public boolean isAppRunning = true;
   public final int timerRate = 500;    // Execute timer task every 500mS

   public void setIsAppRunning(boolean v){
      isAppRunning = v;
   }

   public boolean isAppRunning(){
      return isAppRunning;
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      Timer mTimer = new Timer();

      mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            if(isAppRunning) startSesionTracking();
            else stopSesionTracking();
         }
      }, 0, REFRESH_TIME);
   }

   private void startSesionTracking () { ... };
   private void stopSesionTracking () { ... };

}
```